# Type Error: req_con() takes 1 positional argument but 12 were given

Tags: multithreading, zeromq, python-multithreading, pyzmq

Basically i am trying to return the ipaddress which i get in a function and pass that as an argument to the other function. Since its an ipaddress, It gives me an error as mentioned above. Is there any other way i could make it better?

Here is the code:

```
import zmq
import time
import socket
import threading
import multiprocessing
from threading import Thread
def bd_recv():
    login to get ip

def req_con(host):
    context=zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
    #address=host,port

    port=3233
    socket.connect("tcp://" "%s:%d" % ((host),port))
    print("sending request")
    socket.send_string("hey controller")
    msg=socket.recv(1024)
    print("received reply: %s" %msg)
class ThreadWithReturnValue(Thread):
    def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None,
                 args=(), kwargs={}, Verbose=None):
        Thread.__init__(self, group, target, name, args, kwargs)
        self._return = None
    def run(self):
        print(type(self._target))
        if self._target is not None:
            self._return = self._target(*self._args,
                                                **self._kwargs)
    def join(self, *args):
        Thread.join(self, *args)
        return self._return
if __name__=='__main__':
    #t1=threading.Thread(target=bd_recv,name='bdrecv')
    t3 = ThreadWithReturnValue(target=bd_recv)
    #t1.start()
    t3.start()
    host=(t3.join())  --> The return ipaddress b is given as a host to other function 
    t2=threading.Thread(target=req_con,name='req',args=host,)  --> here it gives me the error as 12 is given 

    t2.start()
```

Answer (score 4):

I literally made a small mistake unfortunately, all i need to change was:

```
t2=threading.Thread(target=req_con,name='req', args=(host,)) --> this brackets in the host has to be added
```